# creating interactive bokeh plot + using for loop to multiple line plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, bokeh

I am using this code to create a simple plot:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure(title="simple line example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(-5,5),
           background_fill_color='#efefef')
show(p)
```

By running this code a plot with multiple line will be created succesfully as expected.
[image]

My goal was to bring the interactivity of bokeh to this plot by using this code:

```
r1=p.line(x, y)
def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    for k in range(1,4):
        r1=p.line(x, y)
        r1.data_source.data['y'] = A * func(w * k*x + phi)
        push_notebook()
```

And show and update the plot using this code:

```
show(p, notebook_handle=True)
interact(update, f=["sin", "cos"], w=(0,50), A=(1,10), phi=(0, 20, 0.1))
```

Once I run the code above I get this reult:

[image]

I was expecting by changing the variables like phi, A etc the whole plot including 4 lines would be updated. But what I get when I for e.g. change sin to cos, looks like this:
[image]

This means the plot dioesnt really "update" but overdraw the new data on the old plot. What am I missing here? And I want stay with the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Two things:

- `push_notebook` is specifically for making incremental updates to an existing plot, *without* replacing anything that is there
- every call to `p.line` adds a *new* line to a plot.

If you want to have just a fixed set of lines that update in response to widgets, then your callback should not call `p.line` at all. You should set up the lines you want, once, up front. Then in the callback, only update the data sources for those lines, before calling `push_notebook` to update the JavaScript side.

Also BTW the best practice for updating a data source is *assigning to the `.data` property* to update everything all at once, e.g.

```
source.data = new_data_dict
```

Comment: So this means for each line I have to write `r[x]=p.line(x, y)` and repeat assigning new data in the update function.

Comment: Do you know any way to create those variables without using globals()[]?

Comment: You should ask about separate question with code. I can't imagine any reason you would need to use the `globals()` function here, so I'm not sure at all what you are suggesting.

Comment: BEcause you said "You should set up the lines you want, once, up front." So I assume I have to define r1, r2 r3 ... for each line.

Comment: You could put them in a list or dict rather than individually naming them, then loop over that structure. But even if you name them, there is no need to use `globals()`